# memoization in python, off by one errors

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime-error

I'm currently taking an algorithms class. I'm testing a lot of them out in python, including dynamic programming. Here is an implementation of the bottom up rod cutting implementation.

It doesn't work because of the off-by-one error. Is there a global setting in python where I can change the default array index to be 1 and not 0? Or can someone please provide me with a better strategy for over-coming the off-by-one errors, which I encounter a million times. It's super annoying.

```
def bottom_up_memo_cut_rod(p,n):
    r = [ 0 for i in range(n) ]
    r[0] = 0
    for j in range(n):
        q = -1
        for i in range(j):
            q = max(q, p[i] + r[j-i])
        r[j] = q
    return r[n]

bottom_up_memo_cut_rod([1,5,8,9], 4)
```

answer should be 10 in this case cutting 4 into (2,2) yields the max price of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things in Python that may help you.  The built-in `enumerate` is a great one.

```
for idx, val_at_idx in enumerate(aList):
  # idx is the 0-indexed position, val_at_idx is the actual value.
```

You can also use list slicing with enumerate to shift indices if absolutely necessary:

```
for idxOffBy1, val_at_wrong_idx in enumerate(aList[1:]):
  # idx here will be 0, but the value will be be from position 1 in the original list.
```

Realistically though, you don't want to try to change the interpreter so that lists start at index 1.  You want to adjust your algorithm to work with the language.

Comment: +1 for `enumerate()`. In Python 2.6 and later, `enumerate()` takes an additional argument for the starting index, which may be helpful when dealing with 1-based objects.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can often avoid working with the indices altogether. That algorithm can be written like this:

```
def bottom_up_memo_cut_rod(p,n):
    r = [0]
    for dummy in p:
        r.append(max(a + b for a, b in zip(reversed(r),p)))
    return r[-1]

print bottom_up_memo_cut_rod([1,5,8,9], 4)
#10
```

Comment: Nice solution. But I wonder if the insert-based version is preferable to your original version. Iterating over a list with `reversed` is O(1) but inserting at the beginning of a list is O(n). It doesn't matter in the long run, since the whole algorithm is O(n ** 2) but I'd guess that using insertion is slower by a constant multiple.

Comment: You could also consider using a `deque` instead of a `list`.  Then insertion at the front would be O(1).

Answer (score -1):

In your case, off-by-one is a result of `r[n]` where `len(r)==n`. You either write `r[n-1]`, or, more preferably, `r[-1]`, which means "the last element of `r`", the same way `r[-2]` will mean "second last" etc.

Unrelated, but useful: `[ 0 for i in range(n) ]` can be written as `[0] * n`

Comment: Be careful when using [x]*n syntax though.

Comment: True, when dealing with mutable types. In fact `[[]] * 3` will create a list of references to the same list, so `lst[0].append(1)` will give you `[[1], [1], [1]]`.